# How to push an element to the last vector in a vector of vectors?

Tags: rust

I am trying to access the last vector in a vector of vectors (`Vec<Vec<u32>>`) and push a value to it, but I continue to come across errors.  A simplified version of what I am trying to do is:

```rust
let mut pc: Vec<Vec<u32>> = vec![];

pc.push(vec![1]);

pc.last().unwrap().push(2);
```

The error I get is:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow data in a `&` reference as mutable                                                                  
   |                                                                                                                            
   |         pc.last().unwrap().push(2);                                                                                        
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

I have tried dereferencing the result of `unwrap()`: `(*(pc.last().unwrap())).push(2);` but the error persists.

The expected behavior is a nested vector resembling: `[[1, 2]]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `last`, use [`last_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.last_mut):

```
fn main(){
    let mut pc:Vec<Vec<i32>> = vec![];
    pc.push(vec![1]);
    pc.last_mut().unwrap().push(2);
    println!("{:?}", pc);
}
```

Prints: `[[1, 2]]`